# Adding href to tr with jquery

Tags: jquery, find, href, lightbox, attr

What i need is to add the URL out of `<a>` to a tr and open it in a lightbox.
I use colorbox. Here so far i get.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('tr').click( function() {
        $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }).hover( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
});
</script>

HTML

<tr class="iframe cboxElement">
<td class="body">CONTENT</td>
           <td><a href="http://www.site.com">LINK</a></td>
```

The lighbox working but i think i did something wrong with the .attr.

Thx

Comment: Adding `href` to `tr` at the time of clicking makes no sense at all!

Comment: I want that the whole tr of the table is a link.
But i can also handel it via CSS and postion: absolute

Comment: And i found this http://jsfiddle.net/hUMvw/